# ORACLE Counting the number of SIDs which belong to a Username and retrieving the sum of cpu value used by each session of the SID

Tags: oracle, count, group-by, sum

I'm trying to pull the count of SIDs that belong to each specific username and the sum of CPUusedbythesession. in following manner but its not allowing me to group by. Can someone identify where I'm going wrong.

```
SELECT ss.username,
         COUNT (DISTINCT se.SID) AS "Count of SID",
         VALUE / 100 AS "TOTAL_CPU"
    FROM gv$session ss, gv$sesstat se, gv$statname sn
   WHERE     se.STATISTIC# = sn.STATISTIC#
         AND NAME LIKE '%CPU used by this session%'
         AND se.SID = ss.SID
         AND ss.status = 'ACTIVE'
         AND ss.username IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY username;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are grouping by username, you cannot have columns other than username appearing without using any aggregate function like sum,count,max etc. Perhaps you should try this:

```
SELECT ss.username,
         COUNT (DISTINCT se.SID) AS "Count of SID",
         SUM(VALUE) / 100 AS "TOTAL_CPU"
    FROM gv$session ss, gv$sesstat se, gv$statname sn
   WHERE     se.STATISTIC# = sn.STATISTIC#
         AND NAME LIKE '%CPU used by this session%'
         AND se.SID = ss.SID
         AND ss.status = 'ACTIVE'
         AND ss.username IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY username;
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitris Kalaitzis that helped to get the result as intented